# Sidekiq restarts automatically in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am running Sidekiq 5.1.1 in production, I have a sidekiq worker **BulkImportWorker** which import students from xls file to database. When I run **BulkImportWorker** sidekiq automatically restart itself during execution and sidekiq logs gives

```
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp7akpjsw BulkImportWorker JID-c0d9b5a157eeb7f118ab577f INFO: start

2018-03-11T15 TID-gp798yfls INFO: Shutting down
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp798yfls INFO: Terminating quiet workers
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp7akpiqg INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp798yfls INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp798yfls WARN: Terminating 1 busy worker threads
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp798yfls WARN: Work still in progress [#<struct Sidekiq::BasicFetch::UnitOfWork queue="queue:default", job="{\"class\":\"BulkImportWorker\",\"args\":[99,12,87],\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"c0d9b5a157eeb7f118ab577f\",\"created_at\":1520781182.8117564,\"enqueued_at\":1520781182.8123767}">]
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp798yfls INFO: Pushed 1 jobs back to Redis
2018-03-11T15 TID-gp798yfls INFO: Bye!
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn69i0f54 INFO: Running in ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn69i0f54 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn69i0f54 INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn69i0f54 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.1.1 with redis options {:id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-21092", :url=>nil}
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn69i0f54 INFO: Loading Schedule
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn69i0f54 INFO: Schedule empty! Set Sidekiq.schedule
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn69i0f54 INFO: Schedules Loaded
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn6aoo3ps BulkImportWorker JID-c0d9b5a157eeb7f118ab577f INFO: start
2018-03-11T15 TID-gn6aoo3ps BulkImportWorker JID-c0d9b5a157eeb7f118ab577f INFO: done: 4.518 sec
```

Surprisingly it completes the job successfully. Any reason why this happen ? I suspect it could be because of memory issue may be ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you run Sidekiq 3.2.0? Your log file says `Booting Sidekiq 5.1.1`...

Comment: your that job example completed within 5s. I don't think that duration would create such memory spike to restart sidekiq. check `dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process'` if processed was killed because of out of memory.

Comment: @spickermann SORRY yes it is 'Sidekiq 5.1.1' but sidekiq web was 3.2.0 https://imgur.com/a/EdTi5